# Initializing a Circle Sprite Node without using a convenience initializer in SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a Circle SKShapeNode class and I am trying to initialize a circle, but  it gives me an error on the `super.init` line. Is there another way that I can initialize the circle? Thanks!

```
class Circle : SKShapeNode {

    var radius : CGFloat!

    init (pos:CGPoint,rad:CGFloat,color:UIColor) {

        super.init(circleOfRadius: 30)


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24536826/4078517. This should be helpfull.

Comment: You should look at older question, there are many similar to this.

Comment: So should I create a CGPath?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old, but I just ran into the same problem with SKScene and thought I might translate...

You are seeing an error here because you are attempting to call a convenience function from the super class.  The rules state that you can only call a super designated initializer from a subclass.  For convenience functions, you must use 'self'.  As in:

```
self.init( circleOfRadius: 30 )
```

However, if you have also partially implemented an override for the init?(coder:) function.  Your subclass only inherits the superclass convenience initializers if you either implement all or none of the designated initializers.  So, delete the required init?(coder:) function.

That should leave you with the (really strange) error:

> 'self' used before self.init call.

Maddeningly, that error occurs on the call to the convenience function self.init(circleOfRadius:)

The answer is found in the link from Darvydas, in the second answer: apparently, the construction of the SKxxxxx objects is somewhat broken.  You need to directly call the designated initializer init() before calling the convenience one.  This should work for you:

```
    class Circle : SKShapeNode {

    var radius : CGFloat!

    convenience init (pos:CGPoint,rad:CGFloat,color:UIColor) {
        self.init()
        self.init(circleOfRadius: 30)
    }

}
```

Hope that helps you (or someone...)