# got error whe converting xcode6 to 7

Tags: swift, xcode7

The error said that "Use of self in delegating initializer before self.init is called". Does anyone know how to fix this issue????

```
     convenience init(tweet: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    let _contents: String = ""
    //var _date: String = ""
    //var _reply_cnt: String = "0"
    let _like_cnt: String = "0"
    //var _bad_cnt: String = "0"
    let _imageUrl: String?

     //code below is the reason why got error
    self.init(contents:_contents, /*date:_date, reply_cnt:_reply_cnt, */like_cnt:_like_cnt,/* bad_cnt:_bad_cnt, */imageUrl:imageUrl)
```

Comment: And what is the debug error?

As in - what does Xcode spit out in the debug

Comment: Please refer this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373142/adding-convenience-initializers-in-swift-subclass

Answer (score 1):

Going on a limb here, but your variable in the function is called `_imageUrl`, and the parameter passed into the `self.init` call is `imageUrl`, so perhaps that variable is invoking `self.imageUrl` prior to calling `self.init` as the error is stating.

Comment: change imageUrl to _imageUrl