# Swift SKShapeNode not accepting initialiser

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I can't get the a sub class of SKShapeNode to accept an initialiser. To work around this I've tried to go by the example posted here [Adding Convenience Initializers in Swift Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373142/adding-convenience-initializers-in-swift-subclass/24536826#24536826). The code i'm using is below.

```
class Ground1 : SKShapeNode {

override init() {
    super.init()
    print("Hello1")
}

convenience init(width: CGFloat, point: CGPoint) {
    var points = [CGPoint(x: -900, y: -300),
                  CGPoint(x: -600, y: -100),
                  CGPoint(x: -100, y: -300),
                  CGPoint(x: 2, y: 150),
                  CGPoint(x: 100, y: -300),
                  CGPoint(x: 600, y: -100),
                  CGPoint(x: 900, y: -300)]
    self.init(splinePoints: &points, count: points.count)
    lineWidth = 5
    strokeColor = UIColor.orange
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: path!)
    physicsBody?.restitution = 0.75
    physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    print("Hello2")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

}

When initialised the convenience init() is ignored and not used. Resulting in no shape being added to the scene. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What code did you use to add the ground?

Comment: I create an instance of it in the gameScene, let ground = ground1(), then I add the instance to the scene. Addchild(gound). I get the print hello1 in the console but no print hello2

Comment: Try this `let ground = Ground1(width: 10, point: CGPoint.zero)` and `addChild(ground)`. You can delete the `override init() {...}` and `required init {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 0x141E, who roundabout pointed me in the right direction. I found this worked but the code looks messy. The reasons for going about the initialisation this way is explained in detail here [Adding Convenience Initializers in Swift Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373142/adding-convenience-initializers-in-swift-subclass/24536826#24536826). Although I was thrown out of finding a solution because of the use of splinePoints and assigning to a path.

```
class Ground1 : SKShapeNode {

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(name: String) {
        var points = [CGPoint(x: -900, y: -300),
                      CGPoint(x: -600, y: -100),
                      CGPoint(x: -100, y: -300),
                      CGPoint(x: 2, y: 150),
                      CGPoint(x: 100, y: -300),
                      CGPoint(x: 600, y: -100),
                      CGPoint(x: 900, y: -300)]
        self.init(splinePoints: &points, count: points.count)
        lineWidth = 5
        strokeColor = UIColor.orange
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: self.path!)
        physicsBody?.restitution = 0.75
        physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```